# iOS - Firebase call neither sends error nor response

Tags: ios, http, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I delete the app and run the following code  ->  gives the response.

But when I run the same code second time  ->  I get no response.

```
 FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("wall").child(userId).queryLimited(toLast: limit).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        print("response")

 }) { (error) in

        print(error)
        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
 }
```

Sometimes it `throws` ->

> NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)

And most of the time neither the `response` nor the `error` is thrown.

Any guesses what is wrong ?

P.S: 
I've my plist as:
[image: For HTTP load failed issue]
Most amazing thing is `Firebase function` call is not even sending `error` ??